# Why does this code work without dynamicly allocating memory

Tags: c, memory, allocation

The Code is supposed to count the amount of times a substring accours in a longer string and detect the location of the substring in the longer string. My Code seems to work but I am wondering why it worked even without allocating memory to index. Intuitvely i thought that because its not clear how many elements index has i would have to allocate memory to it.
I appreciate your answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *count_substr2(char *str, char *substr){

    int i;
    int counter= 0;
    int *index;

    for(i=0; i< (strlen(str)-1); i++){
        if(str[i]== substr[0] && str[i+1]==substr[1]){
            index[counter]=i;
            counter++;
        }

    }
    return index;
}

int main () {
    
    char *string= "abqervbqyyxöiböxxivxybaböxxrnvrixmxcxpäxyeyoymäab";
    char *substr= "ab";


    int* y =count_substr2(string, substr);
    printf("%d     %d      %d    ", y[0], y[1], y[2]);

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: It's called Undefined Behaviour. Writing to an invalid pointer is UB. UB means the behaviour is unpredictable - could crash, could get wrong results or could even appear to "work". But it can change at any time and with any unrelated code changes.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `index` is not initialised.  It could be zero, or anything else.  The code is offsetting that pointer by `[counter]` and storing values *somewhere*.  If it happens to be pointing to somewhere you don't own, your code will crash with a segmentation violation.  But for now, it's just corrupting some area you do own - perhaps the stack, or your heap.

So at the moment, whatever value `index` is holding is somewhat benign. In the future it may not be.  *Commonly* uninitialised local pointers tend to be filled with whatever was on the stack previously.

There are terrible side-effects of these sorts of bugs.  Right here and now, you see no bug.   But then ages later (in CPU time at least), the code using a data structure corrupted by this over-write will crash.  This can be very expensive to debug.